# Free hand drawing with shiny (and capturing the data)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to allow for interactive freeform drawing in a Shiny App while at the same time capturing data on the freeform drawing? I have attached an example below.

[image: example]

Comment: check the plotly package when you want to capture data points using a free hand tool.

Comment: @Jimbou do you have a link to a specific function in plotly? I don't see anything like this in the documentation.

Comment: Have a look at the first example on [this](https://plot.ly/r/) page. The lasso select can be chosen on the topright side.